# Can I get Velocity inner Method?

Tags: velocity

Can I  get Velocity  inner Method?

```
#set ( $scripts = [ "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js" ] )
#foreach($URL in $scripts)
    <script type="text/javascript" src="$URL"></script>
#end

$scripts.add("http://www.cnr.cn")
$script.remove(0)
```

I dont know method add,remove method ,How I can get method?How I know it has some other method?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Velocity are backed by [java.util.ArrayList](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), so any method from ArrayList will work.